# MVC C# nameof() adding in partial with @Html.Hidden not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am adding nameof() to add name of the property in @Html.Hidden(). But it adds the Partial name as prefix with dot. Here is my sample code

```
@Html.Hidden(nameof(InputModel.ErrorUrl), Model.AddToCartInputModel.ErrorUrl)
```

This is giving output like (see **name** attribute)

```
<input id="AddToCartButton_ErrorUrl" name="AddToCartButton.ErrorUrl" type="hidden" value="">
```

What I am expecting in output should be like this

```
<input id="AddToCartButton_ErrorUrl" name="ErrorUrl" type="hidden" value="">
```

Comment: why don't you use `HiddenFor`?

Comment: That is behaving in same way.

Comment: Why are you "expecting" the `AddToCartButton.` prefix to not be there?

Comment: Are these nested ViewModels?

Comment: I am adding that into form tag and the property name should match. The function is global, I can not change the property names. Just for reputability.

Comment: @maccettura yes it is. I am using the @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.AddToCartButton)

Comment: @PrafulJangid there's nothing wrong with the generated output. That's how the helpers *and* `nameof` work. Perhaps your actual question is how to create a hidden field with different ID and name?

Comment: Then you probably need to do something like `@{var addToCartInputModel = Model.AddToCartInputModel; }` and then `@Html.Hidden(m => addToCartInputModel.ErrorUrl)` or write out the raw HTML yourself.

Comment: @PrafulJangid if you want to change the generated output use [the overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.hidden?view=aspnetcore-2.1) that accepts an `htmlAttributes` parameter with eg `new {name="Whatever"}`. ID and name are *important* though, and `Html.Hidden` may override the attributes

Comment: @PrafulJangid *why* do you want to change the name in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

This is all happening because of 
`@Html.DisplayFor()` 
when I tried with 
`@Html.Partial()`, 
it works fine. Don't know why html helpers not working properly with `@Html.DisplayFor()`.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The Id & name will be consistent if using this overload, why do you want the correct Id and incorrect name? If this really is what you want to do just override the HtmlAttributes:

```
@Html.Hidden(nameof(InputModel.ErrorUrl), Model.AddToCartInputModel.ErrorUrl, new {name = "ErrorUrl", id = "AddToCartButton_ErrorUrl"})
```